# Правильная настройка ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: асинхронность, java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте. Интересует такой вопрос. Какие предельные значения (`loadfactor`, `size` и `concurencylevel`) логически допустимы для `ConcurrentHashMap`. Допустим у меня `Map` на `1000` элементов 0,75 `loadFacto`r и 40 `Concurencylevel` одновременно читающих из неё потоков, при этом пишущих нет. Будет ли все это дело при таких настройках тормозить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выдержка из [JavaDoc для ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): "Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block" и далее "A value of one is appropriate when it is known that only one thread will modify and all others will only read." Так что в вашей ситуации подойдет `concurrencyLevel = 1`. `loadFactor` определяет частоту перестройки мапы при ее росте. В вашем случае, как мне кажется, значение по умолчанию сгодится, хотя, похоже, его можно и увеличить, если память дорога. Кстати, если у вас только чтение и нет записи, то точно вам нужна ли ConcurrentHashMap? (Хотя в последнем я легко могу ошибаться. Есть некоторые тонкости в работе памяти в JVM, связанные с чтением и обновлением в разных потоках, в которых я еще не разбираюсь. Возможно, кто-то ответит/прокомментирует по этому поводу).

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. "Кстати, если у вас только чтение и нет записи, то точно вам нужна ли ConcurrentHashMap" > а разве не обязательно синхронизировать обращения с *зашаренной* структуре данных даже при операции чтения ?

Comment: Есть несколько опасных моментов в расшаривании данных только для чтения. Первое - это тот факт, что некоторые структуры данных используют на get lazy-инициализацию и при неудачном стечении обстоятельств они иногда могут сломаться. Например, из-за особенности видимости памяти. В то же время есть более менее безопасные структуры данных. Например, обычная HashMap на get не делает ничего особенного, так что её расшаривание в частном случае безопасно.

Comment: у меня логика не завязана на Mapе, подходит и List, просто для Lista не нашел Concurrent* структуры. Если я сделаю так: гружу 1 потоком в ArrayList. жду его завершения. После чего начинаю из этого ArrayListа активно читать, допустим 40 потоками, будет ли это безопасно?

Comment: Да, будет.

Comment: If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) - Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Vladimir, примите ответ, если он оказался верным.

Comment: Даже если происходят только операции чтения, я бы все равно советовал использовать ConcurrentHashMap. Проблемы при чтении могут возникнуть из-за того, что в хещ-таблице иногда происходят операции переупорядочевания элементов и это может привести к конфликтам при конкурентном доступе. А по производительности на большом количестве потоков, насколько помню, ConcurrentHashMap ничем не уступает обычной мапе.